# Parsing a file using Scapy in Python

Tags: python, parsing, udp, sip, scapy

I would like to parse a file in Python using Scapy because I don't need all informations provided by the command I used with Scapy.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *
import sys
from pprint import pprint

with open('myLogFile', 'r+') as f:
        sys.stdout = f
        print(sniff(filter="udp and port 5060",iface="eth0", prn=lambda x: x.show()))
```

If I open the file called 'myLogFile', I got something like this :

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP8um.png)

My wish is to only get back IP "src" and "dest" for IP heading, and the load for each tram but I don't know how to do it, I am new in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution, if `f` is the file object you want to write to:

```
sniff(filter="udp and port 5060", iface="eth0",
      prn=lambda x: f.write(x.sprintf("%IP.src% %IP.dst% %UDP.payload%\n")))
```

This assumes that you don't want to format the payload. If it contains binary data, you may want to use Python's `repr()` to escape it:

```
sniff(filter="udp and port 5060", iface="eth0",
      prn=lambda x: f.write(x.sprintf("%IP.src% %IP.dst% ") + repr(str(x[UDP].payload)) + '\n'))
```

Comment: This is right, thanks a lot. Now, I am trying to write the URI of the mobile phone in a tab which is linked to the IP adress. I am explaining myself : The tab is 4*254 (lines*columns). The first line will be the end of the IP adresses, so I managed to fill it (from 0 to 253). In the second line, I would like to put the URI of the mobile phone. The URI is written in the payload : REGISTER sip:URI. So, how could I write the URI linked to the end of the IP adress ? For example, if the IP adress is 192.168.1.25 and URI is 5070, I would like to write 5070 in the 26th column of the second line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You should ask another question: you will be able to provide examples, code, etc. well formatted!

Comment: As I am newbie in Python, I don't know how to do it, I could begin with that in pseudocode, I will need to create a class I presume and put that into it :                                                                                   active_mobiles =0                                                                                             if load = 'REGISTER sip: URI'                                                                          then  active_mobiles=+1 and print 'Mobile with URI is active'

Comment: Ask **another** question. Comments should not be used for that but to comment the answer.